# Interpolation to transfer user input code

Tags: ruby, string, interpolation

I was wondering if there was a way to setup a string with interpolation to have the code in the string run multiple times. (I know I could just put the code in a loop, but for the sake of wondering).

For example, I would like the following code:

```
x = "#{puts 'a'}"

3.times do
   x
end
```

To have the output:

```
a
a
a
```

This issue I've found is that interpolation is resolved upon initialization. But is there a way to setup a string so that the interpolation can be reused?

Answer (score 1):

String interpolations are not made for this purpose. Strings are supposed to express semantics, not behaviours. Don't call `puts` inside an interpolated string.

You can still do something like:

```
def x
  puts 'a'
end

3.times do
  x
end
```